# How do I set the value of an input to todays date when a user opens my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make it that when a user opens this page it will be displayed LIVE FDP REPORT AS OF {Todays date time}

[image: enter image description]

the title that needs to have todays date

I tried to use Javascript to implement this:

```
script<
```

```
document.getElementById("current_date").value = Date();
```

```
></script>
```

```
<input id="current_date" readonly></>
```

Comment: `script { }` (with curly brackets) =>  `<script>...</script>` - make sure your `<script>` tag is *after* the `<input>` tag.  Put together -> https://jsfiddle.net/s69La4jn/

Comment: [Many, many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+simplest+clock+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LIVE FDP REPORT AS OF <span id="current_date"></span></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- date -->
<script>
document.getElementById("current_date").textContent = new Date().toLocaleString();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The JS code to set the `value` of your `input` is correct - although it could be improved by including the `new` keyword.

The issue seems to be with how you've structured your HTML. The `script` needs to be HTML tags which contain the JS logic.

Here's a full example of how the entire HTML should look, in a simplified example. I'm sure your actual page will have more code than this, but the important part is the `<script>` tag, and where it's located:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Your page title goes here</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="current_date" readonly />
  <script>
    const displayDate = () => document.getElementById("current_date").value = new Date();
  
    displayDate(); // display on load
    setInterval(displayDate, 1000); // update every second
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it works thanks! but is there a way for me to make the date time dynamic - make the seconds and minutes move?

Comment: Sure, I added a quick implementation which shows you how to do that using an interval which updates once per second.

Comment: it works, you're a genius. Hope one day i will be this good.